# How to draw a go board with css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to draw a go board with html/css/js but I couldn't figure out a good way of doing it. This is what I did:

```
#Board {position: relative; left:100; top:100; height:570; width:570;}
.Square {position: absolute; height:30; width:30; background-color:#DCB579; border-color: black; border-width: 1; border-style: solid;}

.lineh0{top:0;}
.lineh1{top:30;}
.lineh2{top:60;}
.lineh3{top:90;}
.lineh4{top:120;}
.lineh5{top:150;}
.lineh6{top:180;}
.
.
.lineh18{top:540;}

.linev0{left:0;}
.linev1{left:30;}
.linev2{left:60;}
.linev3{left:90;}
.linev4{left:120;}
.linev5{left:150;}
.linev6{left:180;}
.
.
.linev18{left:540;}
```

They way I use these to draw a square on the board is I create elements inside the `Board` element with `Square` class and a `lineh` and `linev` class depending on where the square is. For example a square at the top left corner and bottom right corner:

```
<div id="Board">
<div class="Square lineh0 linev0"></div>
<div class="Square lineh18 linev18"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is there are 361 squares on a go board and it is not good technique to type them all by hand. My question what is the better way of doing it?

Comment: They're all square, so why bother positioning them?

Comment: You're missing units on all dimensional quantifiers. What is `left: 540`? 540 eggs? Miles? Airplanes?

Comment: Sorry I am new to html so I don't know how I could make them form a board without positioning them and isn't the unit pixel by default ?

Comment: There is no default unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this :

```js
let board = document.getElementById("Board");

// each lines
for(let i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
    // each column
    for(let j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
        // create a square
        let square = document.createElement("div");
        // add the Square class
        square.classList.add("Square");
        
        // instead of class linehx
        square.style.top = 30 * i + "px";
        // or use : square.classList.add("lineh" + i);
        
        // instead of class linevx
        square.style.left = 30 * j + "px";
        // or use : square.classList.add("linev" + j);
        
        // add it to the board
        board.appendChild(square);
    }
}
```

```css
.Square {
    position: absolute; 
    height:30; 
    width:30; 
    background-color:#DCB579; 
    border-color: black; 
    border-width: 1; 
    border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="Board">
</div>
```

might need to modify your Square style to get a better result

Answer (score 2):

Prepare your *#Board* as a grid with the correct number of columns and rows (hint: `grid-template-columns: repeat(19, 30px);` )

Position your *.Square*s via grid-row and grid-column, set in the style-attribute of the div via javascript, instead of using classes.

Answer (score 1):

I would use flex with flex-wrap then you don't have to position each square individually.

```css
#board {
  width: 570px;
  height: 570px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.square {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

/* below styles for demo only */
.square:nth-child(odd) {
  background: grey;
}
.square:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```